# How to solve Python Pylint installation error

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip, pylint

I tried to install **Pylint** in my VS Code using the following command:

```
pip install pylint
```

and the output was this:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pylint in c:\users\domin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (2.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: toml>=0.7.1 in c:\users\domin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from pylint) (0.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: astroid<=2.5,>=2.4.0 in c:\users\domin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from pylint) (2.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: isort<6,>=4.2.5 in c:\users\domin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from pylint) (5.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\domin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from pylint) (0.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: mccabe<0.7,>=0.6 in c:\users\domin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from pylint) (0.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six~=1.12 in c:\users\domin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from astroid<=2.5,>=2.4.0->pylint) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt~=1.11 in c:\users\domin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from astroid<=2.5,>=2.4.0->pylint) (1.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: lazy-object-proxy==1.4.* in c:\users\domin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from astroid<=2.5,>=2.4.0->pylint) (1.4.3)
```

and it only returns the simple cursor:

```
PS C:\Users\domin>
```

And whenever I try to use it, VS Code returns the following message:

```
pylint : The term 'pylint' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pylint .
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pylint:String) [], CommandNotFo 
   undException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What should I do?

Comment: Why do you think there was an error, or anything to solve?

Answer (score 1):

This output shows you, that **you've already got this package and it's dependencies installed** in site-packages of python 3.9.

If you need to install it with specific python version installed on your machine you shold type following:

```
/path/to/your/bin/python -m pip install pylint
```

Same with virtualenv. If you want to install it into virtualenv python:

```
source mypython/bin/activate
pip install pylint
```

Comment: Ok., but whenever I try to use it, VS Code returns the following:


pylint : The term 'pylint' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pylint .
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pylint:String) [], CommandNotFo 
   undException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

First answer is to put python on PATH, If that does not work you can go to the user settings (in vs code) and edit the "python.linting.pylintEnabled" to True.

If even that does not work then:-

1. Copy the path where pylint is installed on your computer.
2. Go to your vs code settings and click on the preferences tab.
3. Edit this line

```
"python.linting.pylintPath": "pylint"
```

replace pylint with the path of your pylint installation.